# jMeter: How can I extract a random value, but ignore the 1st or an empty one?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm looking for a solution where I can use the jMeter Regular Expression Extractor for random values, that are NOT empty "".

[Regular Expression Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Fdz.png)

When I add this expression:
**value="(.*?)"**
I receive randomly all of them. Sometimes the value is empty as in "". I want to exclude them.

I tried this from a similar question here in the forum, but it doesn't work:
$.[.*?(@.value != "")].value

Here is my HTML code

```html
><option data-testid="cyprus-town-select-Agios Athanasios" value="Agios Athanasios">Agios Athanasios</option><option data-testid="cyprus-town-select-Akropolis 35, Dromolaxia" value="Akropolis 35, Dromolaxia">Akropolis 35, Dromolaxia</option><option data-testid="cyprus-town-select-Dhekelia" value="Dhekelia">Dhekelia</option>
```

These are the results I'm hoping for:
Agios Athanasios
Akropolis 35, Dromolaxia
Dhekelia

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps use `.+` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748)

I would suggest going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) instead

The relevant [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) expression would be something like:

```
option[value]:not([value=""])
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T.  This worked and has helped me a lot.